# timing code in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a rake task/batch job that is taking too long and im trying to track down in production where the time is being spent. For now I have started adding:

```
   start_time = Time.now

   # logic

   end_time = Time.now
   elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
   puts "Elapsed time is #{elapsed_time} for this logic"
```

Is this the best way to do this? I dont want to install any external tools in production. I need finer grained timings that method levels, because I need to know what data was being used for each method/section etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get the most bang for your buck using a profiler (like [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/)).  This will show you exactly where your time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `Benchmark` module from the standard library that you could use. It shows th same kind of output as the `time` command.  I would link you but I am on my phone, sorry.